# Impossible to add external font in CSS with Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Sorry I'm new here, my post might not be perfect but I'd appreciate if you could help me kindly.

So the issue is the following one : I can't make the font I download or linked work, either on my h1 font or body.

I'd like the PressGothic in the h1 and if it doesn't work, the Anton.

I've tried differents options :

1. linked the downloaded font files with @font-face
2. calling the front with @import url in the CSS and later in the file with font-family, even forcing it with "!important".

After many tries, only Oswald works in the body (in the footer only).

Any solution other than customizing bootstrap ? Because I will not follow the project and would prefer the other person not to have to redo the boostrap file and well, I would like to learn from my issue so I do better next time.

Thank you!

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Exo';
  src: url('assets/fonts/Exo-VariableFont_wght.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'PressGothic';
  src: url('assets/fonts/PressGothicPro.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,100&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap');
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif !important;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body id="page-top">

  <header class="text-white">
    <div class="container px-4 text-center">
      <h1>title</h1>
      <p>
        test font
      </p>
  </header>
  <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
    <div class="container px-4">
      <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">
        copyright
        <a class="text-light" href="assets/doc/qr-code.pdf">
            doc test</a
          >
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Your code works fine. For me all selectors get their defined font-family assigned.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work at all and I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you imported the external font family correctly using @font-face. Still, after that, you are also importing the font families from Google Fonts, which causes the conflict between font families, which might be why you are not getting your font in your project.

to Fix this remove the imports of the font from Google Fonts.

I hope I've been able to solve your query if not then let me know :)

Comment: it does work with @font-face only. I've tried with and without

Comment: So, I haven't change my code but I rebooted my computer based on your answers saying my code was ok. It seems to be enough. 
Sorry for disturbing, have a good day!